# Magento2: How to remove login popup on minicart proceed to checkout button?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1, customer-login, magento2minicart

I am using magento2.4.1.

I want to remove login popup from proceed to checkout button on minicart and want to add login URL, So if guest user click on proceed to checkout from minicart it redirect customer to login page for login before checkout step.

How can I do this in my custom theme?

Comment: there is no such feature in default magento .are you using any plugin ? then you will have to override that plugin

Answer (score 1):

The popup that appears when the mini-cart "Proceed to Checkout" button is clicked and guest checkout is disabled is handled by:

*vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/model/authentication-popup.js*

One way to achieve the goal here is to override the `showModal` method.

This can be done by creating a theme-level override, i.e.

*app/design/frontend/[your theme]/luma/Magento_Customer/web/js/model/authentication-popup.js*

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/url'
], function ($, modal, url) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        modalWindow: null,

        /**
         * Create popUp window for provided element
         *
         * @param {HTMLElement} element
         */
        createPopUp: function (element) {
            var options = {
                'type': 'popup',
                'modalClass': 'popup-authentication',
                'focus': '[name=username]',
                'responsive': true,
                'innerScroll': true,
                'trigger': '.proceed-to-checkout',
                'buttons': []
            };

            this.modalWindow = element;
            modal(options, $(this.modalWindow));
        },

        /** Redirect to login page instead of showing modal */
        showModal: function () {
            const loginUrl = url.build('customer/account/login');
            const refererUrl = btoa(url.build('checkout/cart'));
            window.location.href = loginUrl + '/referer/' + refererUrl;
            return;
        }
    };
});
```

This replaces the `showModal` behavior with a redirect to the login page followed by a redirect to the checkout page after login.

This code could be added to an extension-level override or mixin, but since it only handles this pop-up, that seems like overkill.

As far as I can tell, this modal is only shown for not-logged-in customers when guest checkout is disabled. These conditions are determined in:

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js*

This file includes *Magento_Customer/js/customer-data* as **customerData**. In the `_initContent` method, it defines a variable that loads the **customerData** `customer` object:

```
. . .
var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
    customer = customerData.get('customer'),
    element = $(this.options.button.checkout);
. . .
```

This is later tested to see if this object has a `firstName` property (and if the related `cart` object shows that guest checkout is allowed):

```
. . .
if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
. . .
```

The assumption here is that that `customer().firstname` will be falsey if the customer is not logged in.

***The following is probably out of scope here, but worth mentioning:***

*sidebar.js* uses `customerData.get('customer')`, which will return data from browser local storage as-is. It returns a knockout observable object, hence `customer().firstname` instead of `customer.firstname`.

These objects require special consideration when used in contexts where a value might be updated after your code is run because:

1. Some other process has updated the initial value asynchronously.
2. Your code happens to run before the initial values are set in the first place.

The following example shows code running only after **customerData's** `customer` object is updated:

```
require(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function(customerData) {
    let customer = customerData.get('customer');
    customer.subscribe(function () {
        console.log("customer object's firstName property is now set to:" + customer().firstName);
    });
    customerData.reload(['customer']);
});
```

Comment: your code is working for me, Can you tell me how to check customer is login or not in this file?

Comment: I added some additional info about checking whether the customer is logged in.

Comment: Thanks @jiheison for your efforts to solve this issue